# Adding Comment to The Post using React, Redux and Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

When i try adding comment to the post i get this error:

> FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() cannot be called with an empty path.

Here is my code:

Im using this to push to Firebase, postId is from Redux.

```js
 const postId = useSelector(selectPostId);

  useEffect(() => {
    // za komentiranje na slika
    if (postId) {
      db.collection("posts")
        .doc(postId)
        .collection("comments")
        .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          setComments(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
        });
    }
  }, [postId]);

  const postComment = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    db.collection("posts").doc(postId).collection("comments").add({
      text: comment,
      username: user.displayName,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
    setComment("");
  };
```

Here is the Redux :

```js
export const postSlice = createSlice({
  name: "post",
  initialState: {
    postId: null,
    commentId: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    setPost: (state, action) => {
      state.postId = action.payload.postId;
    },
    setComments: (state, action) => {
      state.commentId = action.payload.commentId;
    },
  },
});

export const { setPost, setComments } = postSlice.actions;

export const selectPostId = (state) => state.post.postId;
export const selectCommentId = (state) => state.post.commentId;

export default postSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are passing a wrong document id to posts collection:

1. verify that postId global state has a value.
2. if postId is a valid value then, check posts collection and see if you are passing the right id to the right collection " Database Architecture "

that is what the error is about.